# Split String in till first encounter of number and ":"

Tags: python

I have a string `"person:x:1319:nobody,jram,dapp,test1,app1,lasp\r\n"` (for example) and need to split the string and get output only as

```
"nobody,jram,dapp,test1,app1,lasp\r\n"
```

how will i be able to do that?

Comment: Use the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function?

Comment: `s.rsplit(':',1)[-1]`?

Comment: Please give some more examples, and better explain the problem. Why that output? Are all examples the same? Is it just always keeping from the last colon onwards...? If so, please don't make us guess

Comment: yes it is always keeping from last colon onwards and the above solution worked , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses regex to find an occurrence of a digit followed by a colon. Then returns the part afterwards as the match.

```
import re

s1 = "person:x:1319:nobody,jram,dapp,test1,app1,lasp\r\n"

m = re.search(r'(?<=\d:).*', s1)
match1 = m.group(0)

print(match1)
```

Output: `nobody,jram,dapp,test1,app1,lasp`

Note that this solution will still work (according to what was requested in the title) even if you have another colon in the text which is not preceded by a number.

```
s2 = "person:x:1319:test:nobody,jram,dapp,test1,app1,lasp\r\n"

m = re.search(r'(?<=\d:).*', s2)
match2 = m.group(0)

print(match2)
```

Output: `test:nobody,jram,dapp,test1,app1,lasp`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.rsplit()` it will split the string based on the delemiter from right side. `rsplit()` return result as list then you can access the values using index.

```
s = "person:x:1319:nobody,jram,dapp,test1,app1,lasp\r\n"

res = s.rsplit(':', 1)[-1]

print(res)
```